# Cannot validate query results

Tags: python

```
    query = "SELECT serialno from registeredpcs where ipaddress = "
    usercheck = query + "'%s'" %fromIP
    #print("query"+"-"+usercheck)
    print(usercheck)
    rs = cursor.execute(usercheck)
    print(rs)
    row = rs
    #print(row)
    #rs = cursor.rowcount()
    if int(row) == 1:
        query = "SELECT report1 from registeredpcs where serialno = "
        firstreport = query + "'%s'" %rs
        result = cursor.execute(firstreport)
        print(result)
    elif int(row) == 0:
        query_new = "SELECT * from registeredpcs"
        cursor.execute(query_new)
        newrow = cursor.rowcount()+1
        print(new row)
```

What I am trying to do here is fetch the *serialno* values from the db when it matches a certain *ipaddress*. This query if working fine. As it should the query result set `rs` is 0. Now I am trying to use that value and do something else in the if else construct. Basically I am trying to check for unique values in the db based on the *ipaddress* value. But I am getting this error

```
error: uncaptured python exception, closing channel smtpd.SMTPChannel connected 
192.168.1.2:3630 at 0x2e47c10 (**class 'TypeError':'int' object is not 
callable** [C:\Python34\lib\asyncore.py|read|83] 
[C:\Python34\lib\asyncore.py|handle_read_event|442] 
[C:\Python34\lib\asynchat.py|handle_read|171] 
[C:\Python34\lib\smtpd.py|found_terminator|342] [C:/Users/Dev-
P/PycharmProjects/CR Server Local/LRS|process_message|43])
```

I know I am making some very basic mistake. I think it's the part in bold thats causing the error. But just can't put my finger on to it. I tried using the `rowcount()` method didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rowcount` is an attribute, not a method; you shouldn't call it.

Comment: Thanks :) that did it.

Answer (score 1):

"I know I am making some very basic mistake" : well, Daniel Roseman alreay adressed the cause of your main error, but there are a couple other mistakes in your code:

```
query = "SELECT serialno from registeredpcs where ipaddress = "
usercheck = query + "'%s'" % fromIP
rs = cursor.execute(usercheck)
```

This part is hard to read (you're using both string concatenation and string formatting for no good reason), brittle (try this with `fromIP = "'foo'"), and [very very unsafe](http://bobby-tables.com/). You want to use paramerized queries instead, ie:

```
# nb check your exact db-api module for the correct placeholder,
# MySQLdb uses '%s' but some other use '?' instead
query = "SELECT serialno from registeredpcs where ipaddress=%s"
params = [fromIP,]
rs = cursor.execute(query, params)
```

> "As it should the query result set rs is 0"

This is actually plain wrong. `cursor.execute()` returns the *number of rows* affected (selected, created, updated, deleted) by the query. The "resultset" is really the cursor itself. You can fetch results using `cursor.fetchone()`, `cursor.fetall()`, or more simply (and more efficiently if you want to work on the whole resultset with constant memory use) by iterating over the `cursor`, ie:

```
for row in cursor:
    print row
```

Let's continue with your code:

```
row = rs
if int(row) == 1:
  # ...    
elif int(row) == 0:
  # ...
```

The first line is useless - it only makes `row` an alias of `rs`, and badly named - it's *not* a "row" (one line of results from your query), it's an `int`. Since it's already an `int`, converting it to `int` is also useless. And finally, unless 'ipadress' is a unique key in your table, your query might return more than one row.

If what you want is the effective value(s) for the `serialno` field for records matching `fromIP`, you have to fetch the row(s):

```
row = cursor.fetchone() # first row, as a tuple
```

then get the value, which in this case will be the first item in row:

```
serialno = row[0]
```

Comment: Thanks bruno that was really helpful. I know the code was shoddy actually was trying a lot of things to find the cause of the main error hence lots of unnecessary code. Had cleaned up a little basically using fetchone() for the serialno and so on and so forth. Just saw your answer now i'll sanitise the code further. Really appreciate the pointers :)